# Write the result in two columns in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

Assume, I have 4 boxes. I would like to write down a propetry (e.x. P) of 4 boxes from time t=0 till t=5s next to each other in Fortran, like the one in the figure I have attached. How can I do it in Fortran?! NOTE, I do not know the the valueof P for next time step when i write it down.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAJLW.png)

Comment: show the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: It is much easier if you transpose the table. I would really do that. There are also methods available for your table, but much harder. But please show some basic code anyway, don't make people write the whole program for you, show your data declarations and your time loop.

Comment: It would be way easier to get an exact answer if you post a small example demonstrating what exactly you are trying to do. Give us a trial code to get an improved code as an answer. The image you linked doesn't say much, but it is probably a spreadsheet. Whatever a spreadsheet can do, rest assured Fortran can do it better, including output formatting.